# Call to undefined function executeNonQuery()

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo que es parte de una function en `php` para cambiar de `status`, anteriormente todo funcionaba perfecto, pero ahora al cambiar `status`, marcar error en:

`$result = $connection >executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['numFile']));`

El error dice que:

```
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function executeNonQuery() in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\aaa\aaa.php:620
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\aaa\aaa.php</b> on line <b>620</b><br />
```

Este es la parte del codigo donde se genera el error.

```
  $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
    $query1 = 'SELECT quantity, reorder_Level FROM inventory_list WHERE numFile = ?';
    $result1 = $connection->executeQuery($query1,array($_POST['numFile']));

        if (intval($result1[0][0]) <= intval($result1[0][1]) && intval($result1[0][0])  == 0)
        {
          $query = 'UPDATE inventory_list SET status = 3 WHERE  numFile = ?';
          $result = $connection >executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['numFile']));
        }
        else
        {

        $query = 'UPDATE inventory_list SET status = 0 WHERE  numFile = ?';
        $result = $connection->executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['numFile']));
                }
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que la función está definida en la clase `MySqlServerConnection`? Puedes verificarlo revisando la clase o haciendo: `print_r(get_class_methods('MySqlServerConnection'));`.  El mensaje de error dice que ese método no existe.

Comment: Seguro, es la misma utilizada en todos los archivos, solo ahorita me esta dando error ahi, investigue un poco y al parecer era que en ambos casos se sobreescribe  $query, pero no se a que se refiere

Comment: Ah espera, aquí tienes un error, te falta el guión: `$connection >executeNonQuery`, ¿no será eso?, debes ponerlo así: **`$connection->executeNonQuery`**, imagino que esa es la línea `620` que menciona el error.

Comment: haha gracias amigo, si era eso :v , tanto estres me mata

Comment: Mucho código repetitivo es estresante, con el tiempo aprenderás técnicas para simplificar.